# This php code won't work, and I don't know why

Tags: php, syntax

I get this error on my webpage(tripex-network.com):

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')' in >/home/www/tripex-network.com/core/init.php on line 24

Here is the init file line 24, as you can see it's formatted correctly but still won't work.:

```
// Normal autoloader
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    if(strpos($class, 'TeamSpeak3') === false){
        require_once 'core/classes/' . $class . '.php';
    }
});
```

WHOLE FILE:

```
<?php 
session_start();
 
if(!isset($page)){
    die();
}

// Require config
if(!isset($path)){
    require('core/config.php');
} else {
    require($path . 'core/config.php');
}

/*
 *  Autoload classes
 */

if(!isset($path)){
    require_once 'core/includes/smarty/Smarty.class.php'; // Smarty
    require_once 'core/includes/sanitize.php'; // Sanitisation
    
    // Normal autoloader
    spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
        if(strpos($class, 'TeamSpeak3') === false){
            require_once 'core/classes/' . $class . '.php';
        }
    });
    
} else if($path === "../../../"){
    // For banner
    require_once '../../includes/smarty/Smarty.class.php';
    require_once '../../includes/sanitize.php';
    spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
        require_once '../../classes/' . $class . '.php';
    });
} else if($path === "../../"){
    // For alerts/PMs
    require_once '../includes/smarty/Smarty.class.php';
    require_once '../includes/sanitize.php';
    spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
        require_once '../classes/' . $class . '.php';
    });
}

/* 
 *  Initialise
 */
 
if($page !== 'install'){
    $queries    = new Queries();
    $user       = new User();
    $smarty     = new Smarty();
    $c          = new Cache();
}

// Error reporting?
if($page !== 'install'){
    $error_reporting = $queries->getWhere('settings', array('name', '=', 'error_reporting'));
    $error_reporting = $error_reporting[0]->value;
    if($error_reporting !== '0'){
        // Enabled
        ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
        ini_set('display_errors',1);
        error_reporting(-1);
    } else {
        // Disabled
        error_reporting(0);
        ini_set('display_errors', 0);
    }
}

// Process if user has checked "remember me"
if(Cookie::exists(Config::get('remember/cookie_name')) && !Session::exists(Config::get('session/session_name'))) {
    $hash = Cookie::get(Config::get('remember/cookie_name'));
    $hashCheck = DB::getInstance()->get('users_session', array('hash', '=', $hash));
    
    if($hashCheck->count()){
        $user = new User($hashCheck->first()->user_id);
        $user->login();
    }
}

if($page !== 'query_alerts' && $page !== 'query_pms' && $page !== 'install' && $page !== 'api' && $page !== 'query_apps' && $page !== 'banner'){
    // Set path for Smarty
    $smarty->setCompileDir('cache/templates_c');

    // Language
    $c->setCache('languagecache');
    $language = $c->retrieve('language');
    if(file_exists('styles/language/' . $language . '/language.php')){
        require('styles/language/' . $language . '/language.php');
    } else {
        require('styles/language/EnglishUK/language.php');
    }

    // Theme
    $c->setCache('themecache');
    $theme_result = $c->retrieve('theme');
    $inverse_navbar = $c->retrieve('inverse_navbar');

    // Template
    $c->setCache('templatecache');
    $template = $c->retrieve('template');
    if(!is_dir('styles/templates/' . $template)){
        $template = 'Default';
    }
    
    
    // Display page load time?
    $c->setCache('page_load_cache');
    $page_loading = $c->retrieve('page_load');
     
    // Initialise array for navbar items and footer navigation items, and also custom scripts/css
    $navbar_array = array();
    $footer_nav_array = array();
    $admin_sidebar = array();
    $custom_js = array();
    $custom_css = array();
     
    // Get enabled addons
    $enabled_addon_pages = array();
    $addons = $queries->getWhere('addons', array('enabled', '=', 1));
    foreach($addons as $addon){
        // Require its initialisation file
        require('addons/' . htmlspecialchars($addon->name) . '/initialisation.php');
        $enabled_addon_pages[] = $addon->name;
    }
    
    /*
     *  Todo: cache whether the status module is enabled 
     */
    $status_enabled = $queries->getWhere('settings', array('name', '=', 'mc_status_module'));
    $status_enabled = $status_enabled[0];
    

    /* 
     *  TEMPORARY - STAFF APPLICATION QUERY
     */
    $staff_applications = $queries->getWhere('core_modules', array('name', '=', 'Staff_Applications'));
    // for upgrade purposes, can be deleted in the future
    if(!count($staff_applications)){
        $queries->create('core_modules', array(
            'name' => 'Staff_Applications',
            'enabled' => 0
        ));
        $data = $queries->alterTable("groups", "staff_apps", "tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'");
        $data = $queries->alterTable("groups", "accept_staff_apps", "tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'");
        $data = $queries->createTable("staff_apps_comments", " `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `aid` int(11) NOT NULL, `uid` int(11) NOT NULL, `time` int(11) NOT NULL, `content` mediumtext NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)", "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1");
        $data = $queries->createTable("staff_apps_questions", " `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `type` int(11) NOT NULL, `name` varchar(16) NOT NULL, `question` varchar(256) NOT NULL, `options` text NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)", "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1");
        $data = $queries->createTable("staff_apps_replies", " `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `uid` int(11) NOT NULL, `time` int(11) NOT NULL, `content` mediumtext NOT NULL, `status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', PRIMARY KEY (`id`)", "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1");
    }
    
    /*
     *  TEMPORARY - MINECRAFT SERVER TABLE QUERY
     */
    $mc_servers_col_exists = $queries->getWhere('settings', array('name', '=', 'query_update'));
    if(!count($mc_servers_col_exists)){
        // Insert column for Minecraft query IP
        $data = $queries->alterTable("mc_servers", "query_ip", "varchar(64) NOT NULL");
        
        // Insert column for Gravatar in users table
        $data = $queries->alterTable("users", "gravatar", "tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'");
        
        // Also for last online column
        $data = $queries->alterTable("users", "last_online", "int(11) DEFAULT NULL");
        
        // Input data into settings so this step doesn't happen again
        $queries->create('settings', array(
            'name' => 'query_update',
            'value' => 'false'
        ));
    }
    $mc_servers_col_exists = null;
    
    // Get enabled modules
    $modules = $queries->getWhere('core_modules', array('enabled', '=', 1));
    foreach($modules as $module){
        // Require its initialisation file
        require('core/modules/' . htmlspecialchars($module->name) . '/initialisation.php');
    }

    // Get site name from cache
    $c->setCache('sitenamecache');
    $sitename = htmlspecialchars($c->retrieve('sitename'));
    $smarty->assign('SITE_NAME', $sitename);

    // Perform tasks for signed in users
    if($user->isLoggedIn()){
        
        // Update a user's IP
        $ip = $user->getIP();
        if(filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)){
            $user->update(array(
                'lastip' => $ip
            ));
        }
        
        // Update user last online
        $queries->update('users', $user->data()->id, array(
            'last_online' => date('U')
        ));
        
        // Perform moderator actions
        if($user->canViewMCP($user->data()->id)){
            // Are there any open reports for moderators?
            $reports = $queries->getWhere('reports', array('status' , '<>', '1'));
            if(count($reports)){
                $reports = true; // Open reports
            } else {
                $reports = false; // No open reports
            }
        }

        // Initial private message and alert check
        $pms = $queries->getWhere('private_messages_users', array('user_id', '=', $user->data()->id));

        $unread_pms = array();
        foreach($pms as $pm){
            if($pm->read != 1){
                $pm_query = $queries->getWhere('private_messages', array('id', '=', $pm->pm_id));
                $unread_pms[] = $pm_query[0];
            }
        }
        
        $alerts = $queries->getWhere('alerts', array('user_id', '=', $user->data()->id));

        $unread_alerts = array();
        foreach($alerts as $alert){
            if($alert->read != 1){
                $unread_alerts[] = $alert;
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

**New error**

> Warning: require_once(core/classes/Cookie.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/www/tripex-network.com/core/init.php on line 26
>
> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'core/classes/Cookie.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5.3/lib//php') in /home/www/tripex-network.com/core/init.php on line 26

**New problem**

> Warning: file_get_contents(minecraft.net/haspaid.jsp?user=xCodr) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/www/tripex-network.com/core/classes/Validate.php on line 60

Comment: look if the code before line 24 has the correct synthax.

Comment: when missing a ; or } on previous lines the compiler often gives error in the wrong place

Comment: updated with whole file

Comment: where? I do not see anything wrong

Comment: the code is correct. please check the file core/config.php and other included files

Comment: I'll add the config.php to the thread.

Comment: What is your PHP version? Anonymous functions are available since PHP 5.3.

Comment: correction, the config file is empty

Comment: Let me check charlotte

Comment: `config.php` doesn't matter. The compiler reports a syntax error. The inclusion is processed on runtime but the PHP code didn't run.

Comment: it was 5.2, I am updating it now

Comment: Yeah, please update it to a **currently supported** PHP version.

Comment: Updating my php version did fix the error, although it arose a new one.

Comment: Warning: require_once(core/classes/Cookie.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/www/tripex-network.com/core/init.php on line 26

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'core/classes/Cookie.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5.3/lib//php') in /home/www/tripex-network.com/core/init.php on line 26

Comment: you can see the error live at tripex-network.com

Comment: There is no such file `core/classes/Cookie.php`. *NIX is case-sensitive, please check the filename and correct it!

Comment: Ah, just one moment please.

Comment: Yea my directory was messed up lol -.-

Comment: another issue:

Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.minecraft.net/haspaid.jsp?user=xCodr) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/www/tripex-network.com/core/classes/Validate.php on line 60